# How do I start two activities at same time?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to start two activities `A` and `B`.  I want `A` to be in the foreground and I want `B` to be in the background.

At some point, I want to switch the order of the two Activities: `A` is moved to the background and `B` is moved to the foreground.

**But here there are three different activities comes live, Acitivity A will start actvity B in bacground and activity C in foreground**

Comment: I don't think the background activity is a activity. It.seems like more property to call it service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below link to start one of your activity in background

[Sending Activity to background without finishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041891/sending-activity-to-background-with-out-finishing)

Other activity which you want to start in foreground can be started normally.

Comment: But here there are three different activities comes , Acitivity A will start actvity B in bacground and activity C in foreground.

Comment: Activity A will start activity B (using above link) which will run in background. This means Activity A is still in foreground. Hence Activity A can start Activity C as normal activity that will run in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to do this.  Activities in Android are meant to be shown to a user and be interacted with.  If you launch more than one Activity, there is no guarantee that your other Activity will even be around when you need to display it.

Perhaps it would help to know more about what you are trying to accomplish.

If you want to have code running in the background, you should consider writing a `Service` or an `AsyncTask`.

Service: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

AsyncTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: +1 for mentioning correct usage of Activities i.e., they're meant to be shown to a user! [More about activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html)

Comment: Yes they are meant to be shown. But who said that they are meant to be shown immediately. I can push 2 Activities at once, the latter will bepresented, the former will also be shown after user presses BACK button.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, if you are asking whether or not you can start two activities at the same time? The answer is no, Android's mechanism is such that an activity can start another activity and so forth.

Read this for more reference on how you can start and use activities.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Moreover read this to understand how you can switch between your activities to get the desired result http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do what you want:

1. The first way is to launch one of the activities (the one you want "in the background") and have that `Activity` launch the other one (the one you want "in the foreground") immediately (in `onCreate()`. When the top `Activity` is finished, the other one (the "background" `Activity`) will be shown.
2. The second way to do this is to simply launch the `Activity` that you want to be in the "foreground". In this `Activity` you can override `onBackPressed()` to launch the other ("background") `Activity`. In this way, the user experience is as you desire, but you don't need to launch the "background" `Activity` until it needs to be shown to the user. Depending on your requirements, you can also switch back and forth between these 2 activities, by simply calling `startActivity()` with an `Intent` where you have set `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` when you want to move from one `Activity` to another. In this case, Android will bring an existing instance of the target `Activity` to the front of the task (if it exists) or will launch a new instance of the target `Activity` (if one does not already exist).

However, none of your terminology is correct and that causes problems when communicating with other developers. An `Activity` isn't in the "foreground" or the "background". These terms are used when talking about **tasks**. A task is in the "foreground" when the user is interacting with it and it is shown on screen. Other tasks are in the "background". A task is made up of one (or more) activities, and they are stacked in such a way that the top-most `Activity` is the one that the user is interacting with. The other activities in the task are not "in the background", they are just paused.