# simulate Home button behavior inside an activity

Tags: android, background, android-activity

I would like to simulate behavior of soft Home button. I'd like that when user tap back button in a specific Activity of my application, this go in background and show device homepage. How can i do (i know i should override onBackPressed() inside activity )

Comment: Similar question [asked here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7071289/1051783)

Comment: It's not similar, in that case user need to return to parent activity.  I need to simulate the pressure of home button, and don't show parent activity :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know how to override `onBackPressed()` then override this method and in this method do like:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent l = new Intent(Friend_list.this, HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(l);
}
```