# Do not kill the activity on back key pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two Activity A and B.

1. Launched Activity A.
2. Started Activity A ---> Activity B
3. On Backey pressed Activity B is destroying and navigating to A.

I do not want to destroy the Activity B, maintain in stack to reuse the same activity when i navigate from A to B again.

Actual:
Activity B is loading URL in webview oncreate which creating every time and reloads the URL.

Expected:
It should start Activity A to Activity B by not creating and should not reload again.

Comment: So you want to "hide" the activity, instead of destroying it. Check this out - [onbackpressed to hide not destroy activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914040/onbackpressed-to-hide-not-destroy-activity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Activity to background without finishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041891/sending-activity-to-background-without-finishing)

Comment: when i use moveTaskToBack(true); it is taking Activity B to background. It doesn't help me. It should go to Activity A. When again i navigate to B, it should not recreate.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

It'll move your activity to Stack and it'll remain there when you'll return. 
For more details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914040/onbackpressed-to-hide-not-destroy-activity/23759328)

Comment: I don't want to hide the activity. It should navigate to Activity A without destroying Activity B to reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
this.startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this,ActivityA.class));  
}
```

*Override the `onBackPressed()` in ActivityB and then launch the activity A*

Comment: In this scenario navigating to Activity A, but URL is reloading in webview when i navigate again to Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

From Activity B, below code will not destroy the Activity B and navigate to A

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
this.startActivity(new Intent(ActivityB.this,ActivityA.class));  
}
```

Navigating from Activity A to B, set below flag to intent which will not recreate the activity.

```
setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
```

Thanks.