# Android - Very slow finishing of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a "Close" button which closes the application.
I have tried 2 methods but they both are very slow.

1. Finishing the activity:

```
activity.finish()
```

2. Sending Home Page intent (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45347172/8916217))

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

How can I close the activity or send it to the background faster?
Why clicking on the "home" button is **much** faster than sending `ACTION_MAIN` intent?

Comment: How slow. Your question doesn't explain for what purpose you are having this problem.

Comment: @snorlax After clicking the "close" button I want the activity to close/be sent to the background. Both methods are slow, meaning "laggy", it takes 2-3 seconds to the home page to load completely. While clicking on the device`s "Home" button does so quite immediately.

Comment: It's still unclear why you notice this lag. Finishing an activity is fast; firing an intent can be fast, but still many layers will be involved (from sending it to receiving it on the other end). I haven't looked at the Android Source code for the Home button but I doubt it sends an intent... all that being said, I do not notice this "2-3 seconds" lag when finishing an activity. Do you have a big task? Does your activity need to save a lot of state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing the **HOME** Button will call `onPause()` on the current `Activity`. Thus it's not closing the app in total but pause it.

*Ergo*: It is of course much faster even in starting because it keeps the memory.

Now you know how to pause the app instead of closing if you want to have a fast approach.

---

If you want to close the whole app I would suggest to use `finishAndRemoveTask();`

> Finishes all activities in this task and removes it from the recent
> tasks list.

Note: **BACK** Button will call `onDestroy()` if you want to have another way. Try out what fits best for your usage.

---

### CODE EXAMPLE

Close app like **HOME** Button programmatically without a transparent `View` using a `Button`:

```
Button close = findViewById(R.id.myCloseButton);
        close.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            finishAffinity();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to trigger, programmatically, the Activity.onPause() method (without creating and invoking a transparent activity)?

Comment: I updated my answer with a code example to get the approach of the original Home Button. Feel free to mark my question as correct if it helped you. Cheers and happy Coding! :)